# Launch failed- Binaray not found

Tags: c, eclipse, project

Hi i get this error when i try to launch this program(i clicked on button build all). Is it maybe because I named my source file wrong. Does it matter how you name it? I named previous source file something completly different and it didnt even recognised function printf. Anyone please explain to me how this works.[image]

Comment: Select a new console program?

Comment: How to you do that? Also does the name od source file matter.

Comment: the display looks like `Eclipse` !! While I would use a more expressive program name than `1.c`  (assuming that the Eclipse IDE is setup properly) it should require a single button push of the `green circle with right arrow` to compile/link/run the program.  However, note the caveat: the IDE must be setup correctly.

Comment: setup involves: the menu 'project' must be used to open a project, the project/build automatically must be selected.  the menu `window/preferences/c/c++ must have been selected and the resulting sub windows properly filled out. the menu `/project/ must have the associated file names included into the project/run configurations must be setup, etc etc.  It helps immensely to use the menu `file/wizard` to setup the project.